# how to use Pytest automation to set GPS fake location and send fake location to a android app/google map

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

I need the help to know the feasibility, and if yes, like to get some ideas how to use python Pytest automation framework to set a GPS fake location (lat, long) and send that location details to a android app/google map using a direct ADB commands in Appium or other ways.

Appreciate your ideas/clues/hints in advance.

From my search, what i can do is, Use PyTest script with GPXPy package, send the data through Appium setLocation API and do this in loop if required. Will this work?